# What is an intuitive explanation of the Hopf fibration and the twisted Hopf fibration?

Tags: algebraic-topology, differential-geometry, geometric-topology, differential-topology

As the question suggests, what is an intuitive explanation of the Hopf fibration and the twisted Hopf fibration? I not a topologist by trade and I find the concept kind of hard to understand... Thanks in advance.